How to assemble large data cube for efficient handling with`terra`?
My raster files are organized hierarchically in folders according to simulation, variable and time span. How would an adept terra user assemble and load the data cube for efficient posterior data analysis, i.e. flexible sub-setting across different dimensions?
Currently I parse the folder structure and store all attributes in a data frame, import the respective raster as a list into an additional column, then collect different layers as needed into a larger raster. However this process is a bit cumbersome so I wondered, how the long-time users would go about this.

You might want to look at stars in this context (it has 'cubes'). And to make clearer your current process, you'd put code that presents your second paragraph process above, with some example data.

What format are your raster files? 2D, 3D? In what dimension(s) differs the "larger raster" from the raster files? What process do you apply?

I would select the files I need by subsetting the data.frame d according to some criterion and do
x <- rast(d$filename)

I would not add the any SpatRasters to a data.frame or list.

Is it possible to create a data cube like in {stars} taking into account the fourth dimension (time)?

time is normally the 3rd dimension (layers) and there is explicit support for that.  But it can be anyting. If you have additional dimensions, you can treat these as variables in a SpatRasterDatasets (or a list thereof) --- I think it is easier to keep track of things that way.
